# Java ProcessBuilder Limits

Tags: java, sockets, communication, processbuilder

I have a Java program that connects to a local server via sockets and I would like to not have to start the server manually if Java detects that it isn't running. So if Java is not connected to the server then I use a ProcessBuilder to start it:

```
new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "./start_server"}).start();
```

Which starts the server, and runs for about 4 minutes, until the server process doesn't respond. It's interesting that if I send more commands it takes less time for this to happen. I'm wondering if I am hitting a limitation of ProcessBuilder, possibly using too much memory. I print the communication to the server on the server side, since this is being called from ProcessBuilder I assume it's being directed elsewhere and herein lies the problem.

Comment: Does this only occur when using `ProcessBuilder` to start your server? Have you tested it without `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: Yeah when I start the server manually it doesn't have any issues

Comment: How do you send the commands to the server? And yes, if you want to read the output of your child process, you need to read its output stream or start the child process in a way that it redirects its output.

Comment: I send ASCII commands via sockets. I don't particularly care about reading the output of the child process, if I want to do that I can just start it manually and see it all in the terminal. But I'm concerned that my output is filling a buffer or something and that's where the issue is being caused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You HAVE to read the output (even if you just throw it away), both stdout and stderr. Otherwise the output buffer will fill up leading to odd behavior.

The simplest approach would be to redirect to the bit bucket (assuming Java 1.7+):

```
File bitbucket;

if (isWindows()) {
    bitbucket = new File("NUL");
} else {
    bitbucket = new File("/dev/null");
}

Process process = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "./start_server")
                  .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.appendTo(bitbucket))
                  .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.appendTo(bitbucket))
                  .start();
```

But if you have to use Java 1.6 or lower, you have to roll your own. This is what I use in my projects:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class StreamConsumer
{
    private final InputStream stream;

    private StreamConsumer(InputStream is)
    {
        this.stream = is;
    }

    private Runnable worker()
    {
        return new Worker();
    }

    private class Worker implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))) {
                while (br.readLine() != null) {
                    /* No one cares */
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                /* No one cares */
            }
        }
    }

    public static void consume(InputStream stream, String label)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new StreamConsumer(stream).worker(), label);
        t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

And you would call it either like this:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "./start_server")
                      .start();

StreamConsumer.consume(process.getInputStream(), "STDOUT");
StreamConsumer.consume(process.getErrorStream(), "STDERR");
```

Or like this:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "./start_server")
                      .redirectErrorStream(true)
                      .start();

StreamConsumer.consume(process.getInputStream(), "STDOUT/STDERR");
```

Note that the `ProcessBuilder` constructor takes a `String...` (varargs), not a `String[]` (although you can create and pass the `String[]` manually if you want)

Comment: This worked like a champ thanks! It was confusing because a couple places it said that if you didn't read the buffer it wouldn't work at all, but mine worked for a good while before it died. Again thank you!

Comment: I have a program of my own utilising ProcessBuilder which utilises pretty much all of my system CPU while trying to run a linux command [as a multi threaded process]. Is there a way to minimise the resource usage of ProcessBuilder?